# When i'm listening to the Resize event of PictureBox and giving PictureBox new image, it wont resize

Tags: c#, winforms

I am drawing graphics on a PictureBox, and because image should change, while resizing, i'm listening to Resize event of PictureBox. When i play the application, no change in the image. It doesn't resizes, thou it's anchored to all directions.

I tried to dispose all resources and redecalre them, i tried to use resizing of image initialisation, but nothing works

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CollisionTest {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        private Bitmap drawingBitmap;
        private Graphics canvasGraphics;

        public Graphics CanvasGraphics { get => canvasGraphics; }

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CanvasResize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            label1.Text = $"{Canvas.Width}, {Canvas.Height}";
            Canvas.Image.Dispose();
            // I think problem's here
            Canvas.Image = new Bitmap(Canvas.Width, Canvas.Height);
            canvasGraphics.Dispose();
            canvasGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(Canvas.Image);
            canvasGraphics.Clear(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255));
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Canvas.Image = new Bitmap(Canvas.Width, Canvas.Height);
            canvasGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(Canvas.Image);
            canvasGraphics.Clear(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255));
            Canvas.Resize += CanvasResize;
        }
    }
}
```

I ecpectected PictureBox to resize, but no change in PictureBox size.

Comment: What is that you're trying to do? You're not painting anything, you're just setting a blank Image as the PictureBox Image property. If you really want to paint something on the control, subscribe to the Paint event an do your drawing there.

Comment: still i'm not drawing anything, but test the code and see for yourself

Comment: Remove everything and just subscribe to the Paint event. Draw what you need to draw there (using the Graphics object provided by `PaintEventArgs`). If you need to draw something on a Bitmap, to save the drawing, draw your final drawings on a new Bitmap and save it. Btw, don't this: `private Graphics canvasGraphics;`. If you need a Graphics object, create one, with a `using` statement, when needed.